# file path in WebApplication using GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm using a class to get a property file under the source folder. But it doesn't work! After checking, I found that the default path by using

```
File f = new File("/src/ss.properties");
```

is not the web application path but the glassfish config path! What can I do if I want to fetch the property file stored in the "classes" path? Usually the default path is the project path, you know.

I've used the `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("sss")` .But it returns null! I'm sure the file name is correct because I've tried it in another simple Java app.

**Update**: Using

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sectionMapping.properties");
```

instead of

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sectionMapping.properties")
```

did the trick! I wonder why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `getResourceAsStream`, or similar. See [this post](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) for how to access resources. (This is independent of Glassfish - it applies to all Java EE app servers.)

See also [this JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html).

**Update:** If your file is in the location `src/ss.properties`, check that it has been copied to `WEB-INF/classes`. Then, you should be able to access it with the following code:

```
InputStream propStream = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("ss.properties");
```

or (note leading slash if using the method in `java.lang.Class`)

```
InputStream propStream = Class.getResourceAsStream("/ss.properties");
```

Note that the full file name (including the `.properties` extension) needs to be used.

If neither of these work, please replace the `getResourceAsStream` call with `getResource(...).openStream()` and post details of the exception which should be thrown.