# read from file that located in resources glassfish java

Tags: java, json, maven, glassfish

I have a maven java ee application

[image]

Path to the file is

```
~/Work/appname/WebContent/resources/json/menu.json
```

After deploying on glassfish file located here:

```
~/Tools/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/appname/resources/json/menu.json
```

[image]
In this file stores menu in json format.
I need to do basic crud (create, read, update, delete) operations with this file.

I've tried to get file like this:

```
InputStream inputStream  = ModulMenuUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/menu.json");
```

I get a NullPointerException. I don't know how to get path to this file. Please help me.

Comment: I also try InputStream inputStream  = ModulMenuUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json/menu.json"); Don't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `json` folder and the file are placed under `src/main/resources`.

Try the following:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json/menu.json");
```

or (not recommended)

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json/menu.json");
```

If both methods don't work you can also try to put the file in the root of your `src` folder.

**See also:**

- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app)
- [getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(“../resources/config.properties”) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913100/getclassloader-getresourceasstream-resources-config-properties-returns-n)
- [file path in WebApplication using GlassFish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341518/file-path-in-webapplication-using-glassfish)
- [Why does getResource return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877808/why-does-getresource-return-null)
- [getResourceAsStream() is always returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null)

Comment: I created a Util class with static methods. And this solution doesn't work for static methods. What can you do with static methods?